# Зависимые списки с подгрузкой данных из JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть пока 1 списка. Родитель

Данные в список приходят из json файла:

```
{"ants": [
  {
    "rod": "Messor",
    "vid": [{
            "vname": "Structor"
            },
            {
            "vname": "Minor"
            }]
  },
  {
    "rod": "Camponotus",
    "vid": [{
            "vname": "Vagus"
            },
            {
            "vname": "nicobarensis"
            }]
  },
  {
    "rod": "Lasius",
    "vid": [{
            "vname": "Niger"
            },
            {
            "vname": "Flavus"
            }]
  }
]}
```

Вывожу первый список вот так:

```
<select id="people"></select>
<script>
$select = $('#people');
$.ajax({
url: 'ants.json',
dataType:'JSON',
success:function(data){

$select.html('');

$.each(data.ants, function(key, val){
$select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
})
},
error:function(){

$select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
}
});
</script>
```

Помогите доработать код, и создать по аналогии второй список и сделать его зависимым от первого, чтобы при выборе значения в первом родительском списке, во втором дочернем выводились данные из json исходя из структуры (вложенности).

Например, при выборе в первом списке Messor, во втором списке выводились 2 значения из json: Structor и Minor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После создания первого `select` нужно повесить на него обработчик `change` в котором можно менять второй `select`

```js
function ajax() {
  var json = {
    "ants": [{
        "rod": "Messor",
        "vid": [{
            "vname": "Structor"
          },
          {
            "vname": "Minor"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rod": "Camponotus",
        "vid": [{
            "vname": "Vagus"
          },
          {
            "vname": "nicobarensis"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rod": "Lasius",
        "vid": [{
            "vname": "Niger"
          },
          {
            "vname": "Flavus"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  return new Promise(function(res) {
    return res(json);
  });
}
var $select = $('#people');
var $selectVid = $('#vid');
ajax().then(function(data) {
  $select.html('');
  $select.append(data.ants.map(function (val, key) {
    return '<option value="' + key + '">' + val.rod + '</option>';
  }));
  $select.on('change', function () {
    var index = $(this).val();
    $selectVid.empty()
      .append(data.ants[index].vid.map(function (val) {
        return '<option id="' + val.vname + '">' + val.vname + '</option>';
    }));
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="people"></select>
<select id="vid"></select>
```